# Dynamic form problem in vue2: [TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined]

Tags: vuejs2

I have to create a dynamic form in vue2. I want to save the values of the dynamic fields in an named object so that I can pass them along on submit.
The following code is working fine except I get an error in the console when I change the input value the first time (value will be propagated correctly though):

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined]
```

Here is how I define the props:

```
  props: {
    fields: {
      type: Object,
      default: {startWord: 'abc'}
    },
  },
```

And this is how I populate the model from the input field:

```
v-model="fields[field.id]"
```

Here is the entire code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Render dynamic form -->
    <div v-for="(field, key) in actionStore.currentAction.manifest.input.fields">

      <!-- Text -->
      <template v-if="field.type == 'string'">
        <label>
          <span>{{key}} {{field.label}}</span>
          <input type="text" v-bind:placeholder="field.placeholder" 
                 v-model="fields[field.id]"/>
        </label>
      </template>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="buttons">
      <button uxp-variant="cta" v-on:click="done">Done</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const Vue = require("vue").default;
const {Bus, Notifications} = require('../../Bus.js');
module.exports = {
  props: {
    fields: {
      type: Object,
      default: {startWord: 'abc'}
    },
  },
  computed: {
    actionStore() {
      return this.$store.state.action;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    done() {
      console.log('fields', this.fields);
      Bus.$emit(Notifications.ACTION_INPUT_DONE, {input: this.fields});
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

So again, everything is working just fine (showing initial value in input, propagating the new values to the model etc.). But I get this '_withTask' error when I first enter a new character (literally only on the first keystroke). After that initial error it doesn't pop up again.

-- Appendix --

This is what the manifest/fields look like:

```
manifest.input = {
  fields: [
    { id: 'startWord', type: 'string', label: 'Start word', placeholder: 'Enter start word here...' },
    { id: 'startWordDummy', type: 'string', label: 'Start word dummy', placeholder: 'Enter start word here...' },
    { id: 'wordCount', type: 'integer', label: 'Word count' },
    { id: 'clean', type: 'checkbox', label: 'Clean up before' },
  ]
}
```

-- Update --

I just discovered that if I set the dynamic field values initially with static values I don't get the error for those fields set this way:

```
  created() {
    this.fields.startWord = 'abc1';
  },
```

But this is not an option since it will be a dynamic list of fields. So what is the best way to handle scenarios like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation: Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

As I understand it's bad idea create keys of your object by v-model.
What would I do in HTML:

```
<input type="text" 
   :placeholder="field.placeholder" 
   @input="inputHandler(event, field.id)" />
```

Then in JS:

```
methods: {
    // ...
    inputHandler({ target }, field) {
        this.fields[field] = target.value;
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. not ideal but it does the trick. Except is has to be:
inputHandler($event, field.id) (missing $), right?

Comment: OMG. You are right. From docs: "Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special `$event` variable." And no other way. But somehow this code works in my sandbox without `$`. I could name params as I wished. Weeeeir.